# Network Config (Alcatel GPON (I-241W-S) & TPLink TL WR1043ND)

Tags: networking, dhcp, dd-wrt, subnet

I have a fibre to home internet solution configured at my place, the Alcatel GPON receives the fibre cable and a LAN cable is fed from it to the TP Link router where the ppoe connection is etablished and distributed over lan and wifi.

Recently realising that the Alcatel GPON is also wifi enabled I wanted to set it up much like a wifi repeater I suppose to extend my wireless network. For this I connected a LAN cable directly to it accessed the interface through (192.168.2.254), I setup the DHCP as 'DHCP Client' and DHCP Server as 192.168.1.1 and hit apply settings.

With this the page refreshed and I haven't been able to access the config page again. I believe it's because I needed to change the Alcatel GPON IP to 192.168.1.x to bring it to the same subnet which I didnt.

I've tried fixing my laptop ip and gateway according to the GPON subnet and default gateway but still no luck.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that for that configuration to work as "Wifi Extender" you must configure both access points with the same SSID, same security settings, different channel and only one of the must have DHCP enabled. Also, each one has to have a different IP address on the same subnet, for example,

Alcatel: 192.168.1.1
TP-link: 192.168.1.2

I think you should disconnect the alcatel from the network, reset it, and plug it alone to  computer so you can access the config page again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, I realise that and had to finish the configuration but my problem is that I can't access the config page anymore. Any ideas on how to do that?